# Vue Router works fine in development, but doesn't match routes in production

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, vue-router

I have a Vue SPA that's being served by an ASP Core API. When I run it in development mode, everything works perfectly. But as soon as I deploy it to production (on an Azure App Service), I always get a blank page.

It seems to be specifically the router that can't match the routes, as I can put some arbitrary HTML into my App.vue, and that will render.

If I go into the developer tools, I can see that the index.html and all .js files download successfully and there are no errors in the console. This is true no matter what URL I visit e.g. myapp.com and myapp.com/login, both download everything but nothing displays on screen.

I have seen several posts saying to change the routing mode to hash, but I still get the same result with that.

Please see below my files:

**main.ts**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import { LOGIN_INITIALISE } from './use-cases/user-auth/AuthModule';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

store.dispatch(LOGIN_INITIALISE)
  .then(() => {
    new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      vuetify,
      render: (h) => h(App),
    }).$mount('#app');
  });
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>test</div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */

import Vue from 'vue';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { LOGOUT } from './use-cases/user-auth/AuthModule';
import { LOGIN } from './router/route-names';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'App',
  created() {
    // configure axios
    Axios.defaults.baseURL = '/api';
    Axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, (err) => {
      // log user out if token has expired
      if (err.response.status === 401 && err.config && !err.config.__isRetryRequest) {
        this.$store.dispatch(LOGOUT);
        this.$router.push({ name: LOGIN });
      }
      throw err;
    });
  },

});
</script>
```

**router/index.ts**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {} from 'vuex';
import VueRouter, { RouteConfig } from 'vue-router';
import store from '@/store';
import {
  HOME,
  LOGIN,
  SIGNUP,
  USERS,
} from './route-names';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: HOME,
    component: () => import('@/views/Home.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: LOGIN,
    component: () => import('@/views/Login.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/signup',
    name: SIGNUP,
    component: () => import('@/views/SignUp.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/users',
    name: USERS,
    component: () => import('@/views/Users.vue'),
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      if (store.getters.userRole === 'Admin') {
        next();
      } else {
        next({ name: HOME });
      }
    },
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    name: '404',
    component: {
      template: '<span>404 Not Found</span>',
    },
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
    next();
  } else if (to.name === LOGIN || to.name === SIGNUP) {
    next();
  } else {
    next({ name: LOGIN });
  }
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Hey Sam! Could you include the specific error you're seeing in the console?

Comment: Hey, That's the problem... There are no errors in the console. And the network tab shows everything returns successfully (200 OK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after completely rebuilding my router piece by piece, I found the issue. I found that the problem was in this global route guard:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
    next();
  } else if (to.name === LOGIN || to.name === SIGNUP) {
    next();
  } else {
    next({ name: LOGIN });
  }
});
```

Specifically, the `isAuthenticated` getter was throwing an error (silently), so all of the routes were failing before they could render. I wrapped my `isAuthenticated` logic in a try-catch that returns false if an error is thrown, and now everything works fine.

I still don't understand why this only affects the production build, but hopefully this experience will be useful to others stuck in the same situation.